# Insert using listview in c#

Tags: c#, insert, ms-access-2007

My code for processing an insert query:

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= ListView1.Items.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            con = new OleDbConnection(cn);

            string cd = "INSERT INTO ProductSold(ID, invoiceID, description, rate, ps_quantity, ps_mrp, free, totalamount) VALUES (@ID,'" + txtInvoiceNo.Text + "',@description,@Rate,@Quantity,@MRP,@free,@Totalamount)";
            cmd = new OleDbCommand(cd);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("InvoiceNo", txtInvoiceNo.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("description", ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Rate", ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[5].Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Quantity", ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MRP", ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text);                
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("free", ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[4].Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Totalamount", ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[6].Text);


            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); `enter code here`/*error*/
            con.Close();
        }
```

Error: insert into table error on data  mismatch on criteria?

Comment: The problem with your querry is that you are not taking into account the type of the values you are trying to insert. All the values you try to put are of type string, but the fields in the database are of different types. Consider some processing of the values.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably messing up with the parameter value types, for some RDBMS they need to be of same type as the field they are referring to (your ID field may be an integer field, but you are using a string value from a TextBox for the ID parameter.

BTW: You are opening a new connection for each entry in your list view. Move the con declaration / assignment out of the loop.